# How do I make JSON data appear on a Label instead of in the console? (Swift)

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to make an iPhone application that displays stock market data. I specifically want it to display the number one gainer for the day percentage wise. I have two problems: 1. Right now I only know how to display the json into the console instead of on the iphone screen via a label or something. 2. The data I get have multiple data points, when I just want the number one highest gainer.

I will now provide my code as well as the Json output I get and want on a Label:

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        var str = "Hello, playground"

        let url = URL(string: "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/gainers?apikey=<api-key>")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        }

        task.resume()
```

Json data I get, but only want the one single top percentage gainer result:

```
{
    mostGainerStock =     (
                {
            changes = "3.0892";
            changesPercentage = "(+43.57%)";
            companyName = "Cassava Sciences Inc";
            price = "10.1792";
            ticker = SAVA;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.55";
            changesPercentage = "(+33.95%)";
            companyName = "Westport Fuel Systems Inc";
            price = "2.17";
            ticker = WPRT;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.08409999999999999";
            changesPercentage = "(+25.88%)";
            companyName = "SandRidge Permian Trust";
            price = "0.409";
            ticker = PER;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.53";
            changesPercentage = "(+25.73%)";
            companyName = "ReneSola Ltd";
            price = "2.59";
            ticker = SOL;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.59";
            changesPercentage = "(+25.00%)";
            companyName = "Art's Way Manufacturing Co Inc";
            price = "2.95";
            ticker = ARTW;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.06";
            changesPercentage = "(+24.00%)";
            companyName = "Onconova Therapeutics Inc";
            price = "0.31";
            ticker = ONTX;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.33";
            changesPercentage = "(+22.17%)";
            companyName = "Contura Energy Inc";
            price = "7.33";
            ticker = CTRA;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.48";
            changesPercentage = "(+21.15%)";
            companyName = "Renren Inc";
            price = "2.75";
            ticker = RENN;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.2";
            changesPercentage = "(+19.23%)";
            companyName = "StoneMor Partners LP";
            price = "1.24";
            ticker = STON;
        },
                {
            changes = "13.0999";
            changesPercentage = "(+18.41%)";
            companyName = "IGM Biosciences Inc";
            price = "84.2399";
            ticker = IGMS;
        },
                {
            changes = "2.58";
            changesPercentage = "(+17.73%)";
            companyName = "Bloom Energy Corp";
            price = "17.13";
            ticker = BE;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.99";
            changesPercentage = "(+17.07%)";
            companyName = "Flux Power Holdings Inc";
            price = "6.79";
            ticker = FLUX;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.185";
            changesPercentage = "(+16.97%)";
            companyName = "Remark Holdings Inc";
            price = "1.275";
            ticker = MARK;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.8100000000000001";
            changesPercentage = "(+16.95%)";
            companyName = "J Alexanders Holdings Inc";
            price = "5.59";
            ticker = JAX;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.33";
            changesPercentage = "(+16.92%)";
            companyName = "Rexahn Pharmaceuticals Inc";
            price = "2.28";
            ticker = REXN;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.23";
            changesPercentage = "(+16.79%)";
            companyName = "AcelRx Pharmaceuticals Inc";
            price = "1.6";
            ticker = ACRX;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.79";
            changesPercentage = "(+16.49%)";
            companyName = "Orgenesis Inc";
            price = "5.58";
            ticker = ORGS;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.405";
            changesPercentage = "(+15.46%)";
            companyName = "Evogene Ltd";
            price = "3.025";
            ticker = EVGN;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.0426";
            changesPercentage = "(+15.10%)";
            companyName = "Pacific Drilling SA";
            price = "0.3247";
            ticker = PACD;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.075";
            changesPercentage = "(+15.05%)";
            companyName = "Fluidigm Corp";
            price = "8.22";
            ticker = FLDM;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.99";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.85%)";
            companyName = "Ituran Location and Control Ltd";
            price = "15.39";
            ticker = ITRN;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.32";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.41%)";
            companyName = "Trevena Inc";
            price = "2.54";
            ticker = TRVN;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.61";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.22%)";
            companyName = "Golden Bull Ltd";
            price = "4.9";
            ticker = DNJR;
        },
                {
            changes = "2.005";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.20%)";
            companyName = "Dave & Buster's Entertainment Inc";
            price = "16.125";
            ticker = PLAY;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.455";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.15%)";
            companyName = "Marinus Pharmaceuticals Inc";
            price = "3.67";
            ticker = MRNS;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.49";
            changesPercentage = "(+14.08%)";
            companyName = "Pivotal Investment Corporation II";
            price = "12.075";
            ticker = PIC;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.4881";
            changesPercentage = "(+13.91%)";
            companyName = "Eastman Kodak Co";
            price = "12.1881";
            ticker = KODK;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.6";
            changesPercentage = "(+13.70%)";
            companyName = "NextDecade Corp";
            price = "4.98";
            ticker = NEXT;
        },
                {
            changes = "0.92";
            changesPercentage = "(+13.09%)";
            companyName = "Trans World Entertainment Corp";
            price = "7.95";
            ticker = TWMC;
        },
                {
            changes = "1.07";
            changesPercentage = "(+12.85%)";
            companyName = "Veritone Inc";
            price = "9.4";
            ticker = VERI;
        }
    );
}
```

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: I think you should at least make an effort to extract the data you want, a tip is to cast the result as [String: Any] and then do another cast. It looks to me like you can just grab the first element of the array once you have it (Of course using Codable would be even better). As far as assigning a value to a UILabel, there must be hundreds of tutorials and articles explaining that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of examples in SO to resolve this issue. Just in this case, I would like to use codable model to extract data.

Add this struct models to app:

```
struct StockModel: Codable {
    let mostGainerStock: [MostGainerStock]
}

struct MostGainerStock: Codable {
    let ticker: String
    let changes: Double
    let price, changesPercentage, companyName: String
}
```

After that change your code like below.

```
//  let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
//Add this New
if let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StockModel.self, from: data) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Example of first data update to Label
                self.tickerLbl.text = model.mostGainerStock[0].ticker
                self.gainLbl.text = model.mostGainerStock[0].changesPercentage
       }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if I sell this app, I'll be happy to give you part of the profits. I need some help making it "look" pretty too. If you're interested, PM me =)

Comment: I am happy that it is working for you. Also happy to help you more. Connect me LinkedIn or email me: razib.mollick@gmail.com